# React Material-Table onSelectionChange pass data to hook state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, material-table

I am new on react, when I am trying to pass data form `onSelectionChange` property but when I try to apply it the selection of the table stop working

```
const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = React.useState([]);
const handleSetSelectedRows = (e) => {
    setSelectedRows(e);
};
...
<MaterialTable
...
onSelectionChange={(e,a)=>{
    handleSetSelectedRows(e);
 }}
/>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `useRef`  instead of `useState` because it rerender the table

Comment: Would you mind adding some code with your answer? For example, when using `useRef` how do you get the `onSelectionChange` values pushed into it?

Comment: `const selectedRow = React.useRef([]);

const handleClick = rows => {
        selectedRow.current = rows;
    };`
.
.
.
**<MaterialTable**
.
.
.
`onSelectionChange={(e)=>{
                                    handleClick(e);
                                }}`
**/>**